# Properties file injection not working in spring

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to use the properties file and inject it to my fields of a class, but I am getting null .

I have created a properties file called **fortune.properties**:

```
fortune1=Have a good day
fortune2=Have a bad day
fortune3=Have a medioccure day
```

Then I am loading it in the **applicationContext.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
 
    <!-- Enable Component Scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo"></context:component-scan>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:fortune.properties" />
</beans>
```

In the RandomFortuneClass, I am using value injection using **@Value()** annotation:

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo;
import java.util.Random;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component()
public class RandomFortuneService implements FortuneService {
    @Value("${fortune1}")
    private String fortune1;
    @Value("${fortune2}")
    private String fortune2;
    @Value("${fortune3}")
    private String fortune3;
    
    String[] fortunes = new String[] {fortune1, fortune2, fortune3};
    private Random random = new Random();
    
    @Override
    public String getFortune() {
        int index = random.nextInt(fortunes.length);
        return fortunes[index];
    }
}
```

Then I am declaring **fortuneService** in **SwimCoach** class using constructor injection:

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component()
public class SwimCoach implements Coach {
    private FortuneService fortuneService;
    @Autowired
    SwimCoach(@Qualifier("randomFortuneService") FortuneService fs) {
        fortuneService = fs;
    }
    @Override
    public String getDailyWorkout() {
        System.out.println();
        return "Swim 5m everyday";
    }
    @Override
    public String getDailyFortune() {
        return fortuneService.getFortune();
    }
}
```

Now when I try to call the method **getDailyFortune** in the **AnnotationDemoApp** class, I always get null as output.

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo;
 
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
 
public class AnnotationDemoApp {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        Coach theCoach = context.getBean("swimCoach", Coach.class);
        System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyFortune());
        context.close();
    }
 
}
```

What is the error here?

Kindly comment if more information is needed.

Here is my file hierarchy:

[image: spring_error]

PS: I am following the spring & hibernate course for beginners by Chad Darby.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to move fortune.properties into `/src/main/resources`, but let me suggest a cleaner way...

First, drop the xml configuration, it's outdated by several years and everything you can do there can be done via java annotations.

Second, add your property files to `src/main/resources`.

Third, tell Spring where to resolve your properties from, you can do this by adding `@PropertySources({@PropertySource("fortune.properties")})` to a configuration class like this (also note that I've added the `@ComponentScan` and @Configuration annotations here):

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource("fortune.properties")
public class Config {

}
```

Fourth, in your main method, use the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` as opposed to the `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`.  I think you'll find it's much cleaner.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
    Coach theCoach = context.getBean("swimCoach", Coach.class);

    System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyFortune());
  }
```